# How to properly read a .csv file in S3 from Spark? - Cannot read footer for file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

We are trying to read a .csv file in S3 using Spark, but getting this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.50.94.133, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=s3a://edl-dfs-sas-cecl-dev/output/dev/dev10/h2o/extend_subset.csv; isDirectory=false; length=897466691973; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
```

What can be done to avoid this error?

Comment: Sounds like you try to read it as Parquet.

Comment: the command is: val dnd_df = sc.read.csv("s3a://edl-dfs-sas-cecl-dev/output/dev/dev10/h2o/extend_subset.csv")

Comment: This is Scala code, not Python

Comment: here is the python command:   myRDD=sc.textFile(“s3a:// edl-dfs-sas-cecl-dev/output/dev/dev10/h2o/extend_subset.csv")

Comment: And this code never calls `load` so you can be pretty sure it doesn't cause the exception you've shown.

Comment: myRDD=sc.textFile(“s3a://edl-dfs-sas-cecl-dev/output/dev/dev10/h2o/extend_subset.csv")
myRDD.count()

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read perfectly from pyspark shell in spark 2.2
[Check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OTNF.png).

Unable to replicate the issue.